How to reply emails using emayili in R? How to get the message ID when sending an email with emayili?
I am sending emails with emayili, a great package BTW.
I want to send replies to my previous emails.
For example, I send an email. Later, I want to reply to that specific email.
I know that the package has already provided two functions (which I don't really know the difference between them): inreplyto and references.
These functions require a message ID (msgid) as their argument to identify the message that they are replying to.
So my question is how to get that message ID? Does emayili return such an ID when sending an email?

My sample code is:

message_content <- envelope(
  to      = "Reciever@gmail.com" %>% address(display = "MR. Reciever"),
  from    = "Sender@gmail.com" %>% address(display = "MR. Sender"),
  
  subject = "email_subject",
  importance = "high", 
  priority = "urgent"
) %>% 
  return_path("Sender@gmail.com" %>% address(display = "MR. Sender"))
  

message_content <- message_content %>% 
  text("Hello!")

smtp <- gmail(
  username = "Sender@gmail.com",
  password = "**********"
)


smtp(message_content, verbose = F)




Andrew (datawookie) has skillfully resolved the issue. You can find our discussion on GitHub issues and refer to his insightful blog post.
The solution involves three key components:

Specifying a return_path: Ensuring proper routing for email replies.
Creating a unique Message-ID: Andrew swiftly added this feature to {emayili}. Now you can generate random ID sequences for future reference—likely how email clients recognize related messages.
Using IDs in emails: Specify the ID in the initial email and subsequent replies (in In-Reply-To and References).

Don't miss Andrew's informative blog post!

Every email that you receive has a message ID. For example:
Message-ID: <datawookie/emayili/issues/155@github.com>

You can find the message ID by viewing the source content of a message in your email client.

When I send a message using emayili, does the package provide a message ID?

The message ID is not generated by {emayili}. The email server adds it to the message header.
Message-ID: <363de820-2fa9-11ef-0000-f16c3e8a78a1@demomailtrap.com>

If you want to reply to a message that you have sent using {emayili} then you either need to

include yourself as a recipient (possibly via BCC) so that you can see the message ID yourself; or
ask the message recipient to send you the message ID.

Of the two I think the first is a better option.
Orchestrating this sort of thing with {emayili} might be tricky. It's not really the intended application. You can do it, but it's going to be clunky.
 In principle it is possible to specify the message ID when sending the email (see this for example) and if there's demand then I could add this feature to {emayili}.
